# Create object hierarchy with string prefixes

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where a REST endpoint responds with a flat list of objects. These objects have a `String name`, a `String shorthand` and a `String structure` which contains all the parent shorthands separated by a comma `,`. The `structure` property includes information of the parent-child relationship between the objects. Example `structure="abc,abc_DEF,abc_DEF_persons"`. So, `abc` is a parent object, `abc_DEF` its child object, `abc_DEF_persons` the child of the child object.

Now my job is to restore the hierarchy in a Java-based service after receiving the list from the endpoint. They are received in no particular order.

`response.json`

```json
[
 {
  "name": "Object1",   // parent
  "shorthand": "abc",
  "structure": null
 },
 {
  "name": "Object2",   // child of abc
  "shorthand": "abc_DEF",
  "structure": "abc"
 },
 {
  "name": "Object3",   // child of abc_DEF
  "shorthand": "abc_DEF_123",
  "structure": "abc,abc_DEF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Object4",   // child of abc_DEF
  "shorthand": "abc_DEF_456",
  "structure": "abc,abc_DEF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Object5",   // parent
  "shorthand": "xyz",
  "structure": null
 },
 {
  "name": "Object6",   // child of xyz
  "shorthand": "xyz_UVW",
  "structure": "xyz"
 },
 {
  "name": "Object7",   // child of xyz
  "shorthand": "xyz_RST",
  "structure": "xyz"
 }
]
```

`Item.java`

```java
public class Item {
    public String name;
    public String shorthand;
    public String structure;
    public List<Item> items;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name, String shorthand, String structure, List<Item> items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.shorthand = shorthand;
        this.structure = structure;
        this.items= items;
    }
}
```

`ItemService.java`

```java
   private createHierarchicalItems(List<Item> flatItems) {
        // Create generic root item
        Item root = new Item();

        // Sort items by length of structure (null first)
        flatItems.sort((a, b) -> {
             if(a.structure != null && b.structure != null) {
                 return a.structure.split(",").length - b.structure.split(",").length;
             }
             return (a.structure == null) ? -1 : 1;
        });

        // Iterate over the flatItems from the HTTP response
        for(Item flatItem of flatItems) {
            List<String> parentShorthands = new ArrayList<>();

            // If the structure property has content, create a list of parent shorthands
            if(flatItem.structre != null && flatItem.structure.length > 0) {
                parentShorthands = flatItem.structure.split(",");
            }
            
            buildTree(root, parentShortHands);      // TBD
        }
    }
```

My current approach is to create a tree structure by building it recursively, but I´m still struggling with the buildTree method.

`expectedStructure.json`

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Object1",
        "shorthand": "abc",
        "structure": null,
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "Object2",
                "shorthand": "abc_DEF",
                "structure": "abc",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "name": "Object3",
                        "shorthand": "abc_DEF_123",
                        "structure": "abc,abc_DEF",
                        "categories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Object4",
                        "shorthand": "abc_DEF_456",
                        "structure": "abc,abc_DEF",
                        "categories": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Object5",
        "shorthand": "xyz",
        "structure": null,
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "Object6",
                "shorthand": "xyz_UVW",
                "structure": "xyz",
                "categories": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Object7",
                "shorthand": "xyz_RST",
                "structure": "xyz",
                "categories": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This seems more map-y than list-y, but if you don’t mind O(n) lookup, it doesn’t matter. I’d start with a root object to hold top-level “parents”. For each item in the list I’d break up the name (inexplicably using `_` instead of dots) and find or create the node; the recursion part. It’s not clear what the *specific* issue is, though—this looks to be a tree descent problem; I’d recommend spending some time and attempt a solution before giving up.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for the comment, I´ll try my best! I´ve just never done anything like this, therefore it is a bit intimidating.

Comment: Sometimes it takes some experimentation to do something new--throw some code at it, see what works (or doesn't), don't worry about it. It's like writing--first draft is usually hot garbage and that's ok. (Plus recursion is useful to understand and super-handy for certain problems.)

Comment: The very first thing here: avoid re-using names from the java standard library. Calling YOUR class Object is a terrible idea. That is jus asking for trouble.

Comment: `"name": "Object3",   // child of DEF
  "shorthand": "abc_DEF_123",
  "structure": "abc,DEF"` when looking at your example, I would say that this has 2 parents, `abc` and `DEF` but `DEF` wouldn't be a child of `abc` in this case. According to your example, the strucure would have to be `"structure": "abc,abc_DEF"`. Is the data wrong?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You are right, the data was wrong. I fixed it.

Comment: You can pre-sort the flat list by the number of commas in the structure content, or otherwise you have to loop over and over again until all items are used up.

Comment: @RickyMo I´m curently trying to do this, but still need to figure out how to have the `null` values (parent) first

Comment: `Comparator::nullsFirst`

Comment: Are `public List<Item> items;` supposed to be parent items or child items or both? I would guess that you need a list of child items and a separate list of parent items. Overall it would be helpful to know the expected output from the input (response.json)

Comment: Is `"structure": "abc,abc_DEF",` always the same? Meaning that the last part of a structure is always the immediate parent?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Yes. I also added the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the last part of a structure is always the immediate parent, I was able to create the expected output with following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // mix up order of input
        List<Item> flatItems = new ArrayList<>();
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object2", "abc_DEF", "abc"));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object3", "abc_DEF_123", "abc,abc_DEF"));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object4", "abc_DEF_456", "abc,abc_DEF"));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object1", "abc", null));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object6", "xyz_UVW", "xyz"));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object5", "xyz", null));
        flatItems.add(new Item("Object7", "xyz_RST", "xyz"));
        // sort items. Can also be done in createHierarchicalItems method
        flatItems
                .sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getStructureLength, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));

        List<Item> createHierarchicalItems = createHierarchicalItems(flatItems);
        printItems(createHierarchicalItems);

    }

    private static void printItems(List<Item> createHierarchicalItems) {
        //only used to structure printing
        for (Item item : createHierarchicalItems) {
            System.out.println(item);
            if (item.categories.size() > 0) {
                printItems(item.categories);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Item> createHierarchicalItems(List<Item> flatItems) {
        List<Item> parents = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Item flatItem : flatItems) {
            // check if the item is a parent item
            if (flatItem.structure == null)
                parents.add(flatItem);
            else {
                // if not a parent, search for immediate parent
                findImmediateParent(parents, flatItem);
            }
        }
        return parents;
    }

    private static void findImmediateParent(List<Item> parents, Item flatItem) {
        for (Item parent : parents)
            // check if the parent item is immediate parent, based on the fact that last item of structure is immediate parents shorthand
            if (parent.shorthand.equals(flatItem.structure.split(",")[flatItem.structure.split(",").length - 1])) {
                parent.addChild(flatItem);
            } else if (parent.categories.size() > 0) {
                // search for possible parents in children of current parent
                findImmediateParent(parent.categories, flatItem);
            }
    }

}

class Item {
    public String name;
    public String shorthand;
    public String structure;
    public List<Item> categories;

    public Item() {
    }
    // utility method to add a child item
    public void addChild(Item flatItem) {
        categories.add(flatItem);
    }

    public Item(String name, String shorthand, String structure) {
        this.name = name;
        this.shorthand = shorthand;
        this.structure = structure;
        categories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // used for sorting
    Integer getStructureLength() {
        return structure != null ? structure.split(",").length : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + ", shorthand=" + shorthand + ", structure=" + structure + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the print:

```
Item [name=Object1, shorthand=abc, structure=null]
Item [name=Object2, shorthand=abc_DEF, structure=abc]
Item [name=Object3, shorthand=abc_DEF_123, structure=abc,abc_DEF]
Item [name=Object4, shorthand=abc_DEF_456, structure=abc,abc_DEF]
Item [name=Object5, shorthand=xyz, structure=null]
Item [name=Object6, shorthand=xyz_UVW, structure=xyz]
Item [name=Object7, shorthand=xyz_RST, structure=xyz]
```

and a look at the debugging view, making it clear which item has which children.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work fine and is understandable. I had to add a `null` check for lines which checked for `x.categories.size() > 0`. Other then that everythig seems to work.

Comment: That is not necessary for my code, but If you have different constructors, then it might be needed for you

Answer (score 1):

1. sort raw items by depth, ascending
2. loop over items and put them in map, key is the item path, in this case structure + shorthand
3. get the parent by key = item structure
4. add item to child list

   public class RawItem {

   ```
   public static class RawItemComparator implements Comparator<RawItem> {

       @Override
       public int compare(RawItem o1, RawItem o2) {
           int depth = null == o1.structure ? 0 : o1.structure.split(",").length;
           int otherDepth = null == o2.structure ? 0 : o2.structure.split(",").length;

           if(depth == otherDepth) {
               return 0;
           } else if(depth > otherDepth) {
               return 1;
           } else {
               return -1;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           return false;
       }
   }

   private final String name;
   private final String shorthand;
   private final String structure;

   @JsonCreator
   public RawItem(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("shorthand") String shorthand, @JsonProperty("structure") String structure) {
       this.name = name;
       this.shorthand = shorthand;
       this.structure = structure;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getShorthand() {
       return shorthand;
   }

   public String getStructure() {
       return structure;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "RawItem{" +
               "name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", shorthand='" + shorthand + '\'' +
               ", structure='" + structure + '\'' +
               '}';
   }
   ```

   }

main class

```
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Map<String, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<RawItem> items = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(mapper.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.json"), RawItem[].class));
        items.sort(new RawItem.RawItemComparator());

        items.forEach(item -> {
            Item parent = null == item.getStructure() ? null : itemMap.get(item.getStructure());

            Item current = new Item(item.getName(), item.getShorthand(), item.getStructure(), new ArrayList<>());
            if(parent != null) {
                parent.items.add(current);
            }

            itemMap.put(current.structure == null ? current.shorthand : current.structure + "," + current.shorthand, current);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the input into a `List<Item>` where the `name`, `shorthand`, and `structure` are populated and the `items` List is empty (but not null).

```
List<Item> itemList = readItemsFromFile(..);
```

Map these items using the `shorthand` as the key.

```
Map<String, Item> itemMap = mapItems(items);
```

At this point, all Items are in `itemList` and all Items are in `itemMap`.  We want `itemList` to contain only the root objects (i.e. those with no parent) but to have all of the child objects appear in the parent.items List of their parent.  To do this, we'll iterate over the `itemList` using an `Iterator`.  For a given `Item`, if it has no structure then we skip it because it is a root Item.  Otherwise, we identify the parent from the structure, fetch the parent from the `itemMap`, and add this Item to its `parent.items` List.  Then invoke the `iterator.remove()` to pull this elements from `itemList`.

```
for (Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator() ; iterator.hasNext() ;) {
  Item item = iterator.next();
  if (null == item.getStructure()) {
    continue;
  }
  iterator.remove();
  String parentKey = identifyParent(item.getStructure());
  Item parent = itemMap.get(parentKey);
  Objects.requireNotNull(parent, "parentKey does not map to an Item "+parentKey);
  parent.getItems().add(item);
}
```

When this iteration is complete, the `itemList` elements will be the root `Item`s, each populated with its children and the those children populated with their children, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the parent equal to 0 or -1 whatever you want in the database. Next, you will use a method to find all the parents (parent id  equal to 0 or -1) and you'll create a list of arrays for each specific parent id. After creating the arraylist with the parents, you'll go and set the corresponding child in the specific arraylist. You can an int variable for setting the depth and etc.. you need two methods , one for finding the parents and one for creating the lists and recursive the method for searching for the childs and then setting them to the list , the hard part is to understand the second level and bellow of your literation. I hope it helps.